# onDraw, onmeasure does not gets called

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout which has  a gridview:

```
public class ParentClass implements OnClickListener , OnFocusChangeListener
{

//instance variables.
//constructors.
//initialization method:

public initMethod()
 {
  //initializes gridview , set adapters, listeners etc.
  //+ code for adding gridview to linear layout etc.
 }
//other methods
...
}
class Grid extends ViewGroup{

        private GridView _gridView = null;      
        Grid()
        {
        super(MyActivity);
        //code for grid-view initialization goes here
        }

        public void setAdapter(GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            _gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        }

        @Override
         protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
             super.onDraw(canvas);


         }
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i expect that when i put a breakpint in overridden methods of my Grid class, it should hit! Why Breakpoint does not get hit?  Am i missing something fundamental here?

Comment: How is your "Grid" class actually used? Is a Grid instance actually instantiated and added to a parent view at any point?

Comment: yes i can see the items in the gridview, as you see my parent class implements onclicklistener, and the overridden method onclick does gets hit when i click an item in the Gridview in UI,Specific to your question see the comments in initmethodm, that is where i call to instantiate the Grid class, set adapters, i can see in the debug mode, that the class gets instantiated, get the adapter set which has all my items, but the overddien methods of Grid class do not get called.

Comment: @con_9 are you using setcontentview(Grid) in parent class.

Comment: Please show the code where it does "Grid grid = new Grid(context); layout.addView(grid);".

Comment: @Reuben:: public initMethod(){_gridVw = new Grid();GridViewAdapter adp = new GridViewAdapter(this, _activity, items, this);
   _gridVw.setAdapter(adp);   
   MyLinearlayout.add(_gridVw._gridView);}

Comment: @ninad: yes i am, that is why i am able to see the grid items and Then i can click them, if i dont call setcontentview(Myview), i think view will not be rendered, which is not the case.View is rendered, but the onlayout(), ondraw(), onmeasure() dont getcalled

Comment: Your problem is obvious, no? You aren't adding _gridVw to the layout, so it never forms part of your View hierarchy, thus nothing will call its onLayout() etc. You are adding _gridVw._gridView to the layout, which is a totally seperate View.

Comment: @Reuben: Perfect!so stupid of me,Thanks.Y dont u post it as an answer, i could resolve it then.

Comment: @con_9. Done. No problems. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per question comments, Grid was instantiated but not added to the layout, therefore it never formed part of your View hierarchy, and so nothing would call it's onLayout() etc.

A contained GridView instance, referenced in Grid._gridView, *did* get added to the layout, hence the confusion.

Possibly the Grid class should be extending GridView rather than containing it.